derive Lie derivative of volume form by using Cartan's magic formula
The volume form of a 4-dimensional lorentzian manifold is defined by
$$ \Omega := \sqrt{-g} dx^0 \wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 $$ where $g=det(g_{ab})$ is the determinant of the metric tensor.
How can we derive the formula
$$ \mathcal{L}_X \Omega = \operatorname{div}(X) \Omega = \nabla _\mu X^\mu \Omega $$
by using Cartan's identity
$$ \mathcal{L}_X \Omega=\iota_X d \Omega+d \iota_X \Omega $$
I have finished the computation as follows
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}_X \Omega &=\iota_X d \Omega+d \iota_X \Omega
=d \iota_X \Omega \\
&=\sum ^4 _{i=1} d (\sqrt{-g}dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^4) \\
&=\frac{\partial(\sqrt{-g}  X^i )}{\partial x^i} dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&=(\partial_i X^i )\Omega +(X^i \partial_i \sqrt{-g})dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&=(\partial_i X^i )\Omega + X^i \frac{-g}{2\sqrt{-g}} g^{mn} \partial_i g_{mn} dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&=(\partial_i X^i )\Omega + X^i \Gamma^n_{ni}\sqrt{-g}dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&= (\nabla _{\mu} X^\mu) \Omega
\end{aligned}
$$
The second equality is valid because $\Omega$ is a closed form,
the third equality is the defination of $\iota _X$,
the sixth equality is valid due to Jacobi' formula.

Show us what you’ve tried and where you get stuck.

Write $v$ with respect to the coordinate basis, use the definitions of interior product and exterior derivative. It’ll probably require a few tries to get the details right. It’s always hard when you’re first learning this.

thx,I've solved my question.

Minor typo: $X^i$ is missing from the second line.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}_X \Omega &=\iota_X d \Omega+d \iota_X \Omega
=d \iota_X \Omega \\
&=\sum ^4 _{i=1} d (X^i \sqrt{-g}dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{dx^i} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^4) \\
&=\frac{\partial(\sqrt{-g}  X^i )}{\partial x^i} dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&=(\partial_i X^i )\Omega +(X^i \partial_i \sqrt{-g})dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&=(\partial_i X^i )\Omega + X^i \frac{-g}{2\sqrt{-g}} g^{mn} \partial_i g_{mn} dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&=(\partial_i X^i )\Omega + X^i \Gamma^n_{ni}\sqrt{-g}dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \\
&= (\nabla _{\mu} X^\mu) \Omega
\end{aligned}
$$
